# C# Disadvantage of using earlier targeted .NET Framework DLL with newer versions of .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, dll, frameworks, app-config

Its not a problem, just a question. When I download a certain Dynamic Link Library to simplify complex coding, sometimes DLL happens to be built using earlier versions of .NET Framework. What I do is simply add **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"** in app.config file. Is it legal and OK to use this approach? or this is Unprofessional / Bad.

Comment: There is only one disadvantage, you are running that code with a CLR version that it was never tested with.  Microsoft did take advantage of the v4.0 version to fix some very obscure bugs, the kind that they could not reasonably fix in v2.0+.  The odds that this code depends on such a bug are very low but not zero.  You'll find out when you test your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot re-compile the dlls your only option is to use the .net version they were originally compiled with.